# Facebook achievements not showing in the ticker

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

The achievements set for my app aren't showing in the game ticker they are however registered and are being registered with the users who warrant it.  I have also requested the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions but it's still not working.

Any ideas on what might be causing it?

Thanks

Comment: What response do you get from Facebook when you make the request to give one of your users an achievement?

Comment: Nothing it works according to the Graph API Explorer - the problem is just that the ticker doesn't show the achievements

Comment: Is "Social Discovery" enabled? (edit app -> advanced settings -> canvas settings)

Comment: I too am seeing this behavior. If you go to other Facebook games that are known to have achievements (most recent zynga games for example) you will see that they're not showing up there either.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had checked the Facebook status page to see if there was anything on there but it wasn't mentioned. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is the HTTP response you get back from Facebook when posting the achievement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with what appears to be the real answer to our question, it looks like Facebook is experimenting with removing achievements from the ticker alltogether. Check out their post about it on the [FB Developer Blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/641/).

From the section titled **Updating the games and apps ticker**

```
As we work to optimize the canvas experience, we've found the live ticker
alongside games and apps has not been a substantial driver of traffic. As a
result, we are experimenting with removing the current version of the ticker on
games and apps pages, and are exploring other ways to improve and simplify the
games experience. We will continue to show the bookmarks on games and apps pages,
which drive significant traffic and re-engagement.
```

Seems like a pretty lame solution to me but I guess they're looking forward to greater Timeline integration.

Comment: Was just about to post this - found it this morning, seems a shame I quite liked the ticker.  Thanks for posting though!

Comment: Yeah I was a fan of it there too, feedback in real time and all that. Have you found a way to locate your achieved achievements without being in the Timeline mode?